# How to remove or disable Ease of Access button on Windows 7 login screen

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

Question refers to Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

When I lock my computer I don't want people to be able to mess about with it, so would like the Ease of Access button (in the bottom left corner of the logon screen) to either be removed or disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps will remove the button completely:

1. **Create a backup of your Authui.dll in C:\Windows\System32**
2. Open C:\Windows\System32\Authui.dll in a resource editor (PE Explorer)
3. Go the the UIFILE folder and double-click the 12400 XAML file
4. Find this text `<if id="atom(Accessibility)">`
5. Delete everything following that text - it should be 46 lines - stop at `<if id="atom(ToggleTabletKeyboard)">`
6. Save/close the file and do steps 4 and 5 for the 12401 and 12402 XAML files

If you feel uncomfortable modifying system files, there are also third-party apps that will disable the button.

If you are using 64-bit Windows edition, you'll also need to replace authui.dll file present in "C:\Windows\sysWOW64\" folder.

Comment: Nick's answer will not work; it will crash your login and force you to do a sys restore/hdd pull. That method is only for 32bit operating systems, which OP's clearly is not. To date there is no way of modifying the authui.dll for 64bit OS's.

Comment: @user79679 Somebody's edited that in since. It _looks_ like it might work, but I think DLL signing might come into play and cause your described issue anyway.

Answer (score 5):

## Disable the Ease of Access button

Clicking the button would usually start `Utilman.exe`, which in turn would display the Ease of Access options. You can override the executable, thus making the button useless.

1. Open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7).
2. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\Utilman.exe" /v "Debugger" /t REG_SZ /d "systray.exe" /f
   ```

Changes are applied immediately.

### How it works

The `Image File Execution Options` registry key was designed, among other things, to automatically launch a debugger when an application starts. While the debugger would start the application and attach, you can specify just any executable which will be run instead, thus overriding the original one.

What about `systray.exe`? It's a little stub program which was first introduced with Windows 95, and [used to handle the system notification icons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030910-00/?p=42583). It's not really used any more in the newer Windows versions, and it was mostly kept for backward compatibility reasons. It has no user interface, and wouldn't do anything noticeable besides refreshing the notification area when started. Anything launched in the logon screen runs under `NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM`, which has no desktop or taskbar, so nothing will happen.

#### Pros

- No system file or security permissions tweaking.
- Future-proof: works even if `authui.dll` or `Utilman.exe` get updated.
- No third party software involved.

#### Cons

- Although the button won't do anything, it will still be visible/clickable.
- As a side effect, you won't be able to manually start the Utility Manager (`Utilman.exe`) elsewhere, nor the Screen Magnifier unless you use the `/noutilman` switch (e.g. `Magnify.exe /noutilman`).

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to lock down a school kiosk and stop kids pressing CTRL + ALT + DELETE and fiddling with high contrast etc.... as ease of access is the only tough thing to disable with no GPOs etc. Now I have an empty windows security menu. Cheers

Comment: That moment this comment is more useful than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do this is to use **Ease of Access Disabler 1.6** from http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/Ease-of-Access-disabler.shtml. It should work on both Vista and win7.

Comment: Works in Windows 7. This How-To Geek article explains more. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-ease-of-access-button-on-vista-logon-screen/

Answer (score 3):

Even if this is a little bit older, I found a way to remove the accessibility button on 64-bit systems.

1. Create a backup of your Authui.dll in C:\Windows\System32
2. ListOpen C:\Windows\System32\Authui.dll in a hex editor (like Hex Workshop)
3. List item
4. Find this text `atom(Accessibility)`
5. Shortly after the text above, you should find a text saying `layoutpos="left"`
6. Replace the `"left"` with `"none"`
7. Save authui.dll

Answer (score 0):

Seriously a lot of work here when the answer is simple.

Delete, move or rename c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe

You'll need to take ownership of it to allow you to do it but far easier than messing with dll's or even the registry.

Comment: While this may address the problem, I just don't think modifying a system file is a good idea.