# Why can't i disable ease of access tools in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, control-panel, ease-of-access

A colleague of mine enabled the magnifyer-, and narrator tool as a small practical joke. Now it's been six months, and every time i restart my computer, or log off and on again, the tools are reactivated.

There is a button for the ease of access tools on the log-on screen, where you can select checkboxes. I have unchecked them several times, chosen both "apply" and "OK", but for some reason, they always revert back to being checked, when I do my next login.

Why won't my disabling efforts work? How can I disable these annoying tools?

**Some of what I've tried:**

I've tried to disable their startup directly in the control panel, but there are no startup-options there, only options to run the different tools.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5623a9b3-493d-438f-a354-1ee2eca5dcae/how-to-disable-narrator suggests doing so in control panel, but the options it describes does not exist in my windows.

[How to remove or disable Ease of Access button on Windows 7 login screen](https://superuser.com/questions/196989/how-to-remove-or-disable-ease-of-access-button-on-windows-7-login-screen) describes how to disable the ease of access option panel, and not the individual tools.

[In windows 7, how do I disable "Ease of Access" pop ups on the logon screen as I am typing my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/112550/in-windows-7-how-do-i-disable-ease-of-access-pop-ups-on-the-logon-screen-as-i) is the same as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must disable them from Ease of Access Center in Control Panel.
Refer to the instructions from [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/prevent-ease-of-access-programs-from-starting-automatically)

[image]

Also, one of the links mentioned by you points to a tool in [Softpedia](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-ease-of-access-button-on-vista-logon-screen/). Did you try that ?

Comment: I never tried the softpedia option, because it simply wasn't what I was looking for. Your solution worked though! I had just stopped one level too shallow in the system settings, to find the correct options. What I thought started the tools, was actually an option tab. My Windows is not in English, so the translations into my language, might have something to do with that. Anyway, thank you. I've tried to restart the computer too now, and it is finally working as expected.

Comment: also, the on screen keyboard was also a part of his prank, but that one I managed to disable on my first attempt. I can't really say why the two others didn't work in the other menu, found on the log-in screen...